# Why won't my background show within div container?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, fullpage.js

I am using Fullpage.js and so far adding backgrounds has not been a problem. For some reason my background is not showing on one of the pages (blog page). I set a background color to see if it was just the div, and the background color worked fine. Is there something I am not seeing?

Edit: I am using the same file path for the first slide, and it works just fine with that so I know the path is fine.

CSS:

```
/*------------------------------------------------------
HEADER PAGE
-------------------------------------------------------*/

.header {
    text-align: center;
    background: url('/img/paint.jpg') no-repeat center center fixed; 
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}

.name {
    float: right;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    padding-bottom: 0;
}

.name h1 {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: black;
    font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
    font-size: 300%;
}
.name h5 {
    color: grey;
    font-family: 'Yrsa', serif;
    font-size: 150%;
    float: right;
    padding-top: -1%;
    margin-top: -5%;;
}

.social-links {
    float: right;
    padding-top: 10%;
    font-size: 175%;
}

.linkedin {
    color: #1E8BC3;
    transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
}

.github {
    color: black;
    transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
}

.instagram {
    color: #2980b9;
    transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
}

.dribbble {
    color: #FF69B4;
    transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
}

.fa-github:hover {
    transform: scale(1.2);
    color: #222;
    -webkit-transition: all .35s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: all .35s ease-out;
    -o-transition: all .35s ease-out;
    -ms-transition: all .35s ease-out;
    transition: all .35s ease-out;
}

.fa-linkedin:hover {
    transform: scale(1.2);
    color: #43ace2;
    -webkit-transition: all .35s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: all .35s ease-out;
    -o-transition: all .35s ease-out;
    -ms-transition: all .35s ease-out;
    transition: all .35s ease-out;
}

.fa-instagram:hover {
    transform: scale(1.2);
    color: #4ea1d8;
    -webkit-transition: all .35s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: all .35s ease-out;
    -o-transition: all .35s ease-out;
    -ms-transition: all .35s ease-out;
    transition: all .35s ease-out;
}

.fa-dribbble:hover {
    transform: scale(1.2);
    color: #ffadd6;
    -webkit-transition: all .35s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: all .35s ease-out;
    -o-transition: all .35s ease-out;
    -ms-transition: all .35s ease-out;
    transition: all .35s ease-out;
}




/*------------------------------------------------------
ABOUT PAGE
-------------------------------------------------------*/

.about-you h2 {
    font-family: 'Yrsa', serif;
    font-size: 200%;
    text-align: center;
    padding-bottom: 2%;
}

.about-me h2 {
    font-family: 'Yrsa', serif;
    font-size: 200%;
    text-align: center;
    padding-bottom: 2%;
}

.you-text,
.me-text {
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    line-height: 175%;
}

/*-------------  MODEL SLIDE  --------------*/

.model-page {
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    max-width: 100%;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
}

/*-------------  APPLE SLIDE  --------------*/

.apple-page {
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    max-width: 100%;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
}

/*-------------  DRIBBBLE SLIDE  --------------*/
.dribbble-page {
    background-color: #FF69B4;
}

.dribbble-icon {
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 500%;
}

.info h3 {
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    padding-top: 7%;
}

.dribbble-button,
.github-button {
    font-size: 400%;
}


.button-info {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 300%;
}



/*------------------------------------------------------
BLOG PAGE
-------------------------------------------------------*/

.blog {
    background: url('/img/paint.jpg') no-repeat center center fixed; 
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

HTML:

```
<body>
    <div id="fullpage">

        <!-------------------------    HEADER    ----------------------------->

        <div class="section header">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="offset-md-4 name">
                    <h1>temple naylor</h1>
                    <h5>Full Stack Web Developer</h5>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="container">
                <div class="offset-md-4 social-links">
                    <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/templenaylor"><i class="fa fa-linkedin linkedin"></i></a>
                    <a href="https://github.com/templenaylor"><i class="fa fa-github github"></i></a>
                    <a href="https://www.instagram.com/templecerulean/"><i class="fa fa-instagram instagram"></i></a>
                    <a href="https://dribbble.com/templenaylor"><i class="fa fa-dribbble dribbble"></i></a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-------------------------    ABOUT    ----------------------------->

        <div class="section #about">

            <div class="container">

                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12 about-you">
                        <h2>About You</h2>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-6 you-text">
                        <p>Let's cut the bull - What can I do for you? I am a <strong>Full Stack Developer</strong> that will offer a variety of services. 
                            <br>My main focus however is Front End Development. I create <strong>websites</strong> and <strong>applications</strong> for <strong>everyone</strong>, from a customers personal portfolio to a businesses landing page. <br>I believe in creating with the <strong>users perspective</strong> in mind from start to finish.</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6 you-text">
                        <p>No matter how stunning the typography, images, or content, it is pointless if it cannot be presented with a <strong>intuitive experience</strong> for the user. <br>No matter <strong>your goal</strong>, I will make sure <strong>your story</strong> is told whether that needs to be done with a <strong>website</strong> or <strong>APP</strong>.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12 about-me">
                        <h2>About Me</h2>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-6 me-text">
                        <p>I am both a <strong>graduate</strong> and <strong>self taught</strong> developer. <br>My knowledge consists of <strong>HTML/CSS</strong>, <strong>JavaScript</strong>, <strong>Angular</strong>, <strong>SQL</strong>, <strong>PHP</strong> &amp; <strong>C#</strong>. <br>I believe in personal growth as well as learning everyday, and coding is one of the many challenges that provides that outlet for me.</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6 me-text">
                        <p>When I am not working on the next <strong>hottest product</strong>, you can find me <strong>reading</strong>, exploring <strong>architecture</strong>, finding new <strong>music</strong>, getting my next <strong>tattoo</strong>, or pursuing my next <strong>dream</strong>.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>


        <div class="section">
            <div class="slide"><img class="model-page" src="img/modelpage.png">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-xs-12 button-info">
                            <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-dribbble dribbble"></i></a>
                            <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-github github"></i></a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>


            <div class="slide"><img class="apple-page" src="img/applepage.png">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-xs-12 button-info">
                            <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-dribbble dribbble"></i></a>
                            <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-github github"></i></a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="slide dribbble-page">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="row dribbble-icon">
                        <div class="col-md-12"><i class="fa fa-dribbble"></i></div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="row info">
                        <div class="col-md-12 link-dribbble"><a href="#" style="text-decoration:none"><h3>Please checkout my dribbble profile for more.</h3></a></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>



        <!-------------------------    BLOG    ----------------------------->
        <div class="section blog">Some section</div>


    </div><!--FULLPAGE WRAPPER DIV-->

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#fullpage').fullpage({
                navigation: true,
                navigationPosition: 'right',
                scrollOverflow: true
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated, thank you!

Edit: I am using the same file path for the first slide, and it works just fine with that so I know the path is fine.

Comment: The `background` for header is working? Your path to image is `/img/paint.jpg`. This path should be relative to your css file. If your css is under `styles/` your image should be `styles/img/paint.jpg` and your style should be `background: url('img/paint.jpg')`

Comment: This is the same background img used for the heading page and it works just fine. It has to be something else.

Comment: may be `.section` overrides `.header` style.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that the *fixed* property is unnecessary, due to the way the fullpage plugin functions. I would suggest removing the *fixed* property from your background. Thus, your blog class--in your css--should look something like this:

```
.blog {
    background: url(Path_to_image) no-repeat center center;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

or,

```
.blog {
   background-image: url(Path_to_image);
   background-repeat   : no-repeat;
   background-position : center center;
   background-size     : cover;

}
```

Comment: This did the trick!! Thank you so much, greatly appreciated. Never would assumed that attribute would have caused that. Again, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I have saw your code in jsfiddle, I think you  mentioned wrong background path for images.

Comment: It is the same path for the heading slide and it works just fine with that, so it must be something else.

Answer (score 0):

You might have the wrong path for the background image - ~Try adding '..'before the first /.

```
background: url('../img/paint.jpg') no-repeat center center fixed;
```

Basically, since the images are in a folder that is outside of the css folder, you will need to exit the css folder, and then go into the img folder in order to get the image you want.

Comment: Check full description of problem. The same background path is used for the first slide, and that slide works just fine.